# Observer Pattern or just create event handling?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-2, oop

I want to create a "**modules**" layout in my web application so I can easily add more modules of the same type, for example:

**As an example**, my WebApp handles subscriptions and email campaigns, and I want to create an **interface** to allow easily coupling multiple API's, MailChimp, CampaignMonitor, iContact, etc...

so I will create an `IMailingService` interface where I set up the ground rules and all modules will implement it like

```
public class CampaignMonitorService : IMailingService
```

So far so good...

How about **fire the interface method** upon an action on my webapp?

Should I implement the **Observer Design Pattern**, should I simple create event handlers, or any other hook?

for example, upon a user subscription I would like to fire the `AddSubscriber` method on the `interface`

```
AddSubscriber(string email, string[] args);
```

some thing as creating a list, unsubscribing, etc, etc...

What would be the **best approach to handle such scenario**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Event handlers *are* how the Observer pattern is normally implemented in .NET. The pattern is a first class citizen of the .NET world, very much like how the Iterator pattern is built in (with `foreach` and `yield return`).

If you do want to use the pattern without events/event handlers, you can use the new [`IObserver<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx) and [`IObservable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) (introduced in .NET 4.0).

Comment: I believe those were added in 3.5? +1 anyway.

Comment: @Zor - if you look at the documentation, you will see there is no entry for these for 3.5

Comment: `IObservable<T>` is only available in .NET Framework 4, but thank you for the heads up, I will make use of event handling for this.

Comment: @balexandre - yes, it is new in .NET 4.0, as I noted in my answer.

Comment: I was getting at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449%28VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: @Zor - that's for phone/mobile only, not the desktop edition.